# Getting the name of a file in a directory in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, file, download

This portion of the code is supposed to download a txt file from a website. By running this code it is able to successfully download the file from the website and place it into the app's Documents directory. I am able to see where the file is stored because in the last couple of lines in the code it prints out the location of the file. However, I am not able to get the file name that was recently downloaded. The goal is for me to try to get the name of the file so that I can be able to open it and read from it. What are my options in approaching this? What am I missing in this block of code that is preventing me from getting the name of the file that was recently downloaded?

```
    guard let url1 = URL(string: website) else { return  }

    //This portion of the code focuses on creating a download task with a completion handler
    //Completion handler moves the downloaded file to the app's directory

    let downloadTask = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url1) {

        urlOrNil, responseOrNil, errorOrNil in
        // check for and handle errors:
        // * errorOrNil should be nil
        // * responseOrNil should be an HTTPURLResponse with statusCode in 200..<299

        guard let fileURL = urlOrNil else { return }
        do {
            let documentsURL = try
                FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                        in: .userDomainMask,
                                        appropriateFor: nil,
                                        create: false)
            let savedURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(
                fileURL.lastPathComponent)
            try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: fileURL, to: savedURL)
        } catch {
            print ("file error: \(error)")
        }

    }
    downloadTask.resume()


    //If you want to receive progress updates as the download proceeds, you must use a delegate.
    var urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self as? URLSessionDelegate, delegateQueue: nil)


    func startDownload(url1: URL) -> String? {


        let downloadTask = urlSession.downloadTask(with: url1)
        let fname = downloadTask.response?.suggestedFilename
        downloadTask.resume()

        return fname
        //self.downloadTask = downloadTask
    }

    let name = startDownload(url1: url1)

    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) as NSArray
    let documentsDir = paths.firstObject as! String
    print("Path to the Documents directory\n\(documentsDir)")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the name of the file at a given path by initialising a URL object from the path:

```
let name = URL(fileURLWithPath: yourPath).lastPathComponent
```

This returns an optional string. The name will be automatically unescaped, so it will be human-readable (no percent encoding).

---

The filename should be available to you from your `fileURL` variable, as this is where you got the filename in order to save it:

```
let name = fileURL.lastPathComponent
```

Comment: When I print out the contents of documentDir, it prints out: "/Users/useraccount/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AB8E29F4-2F1B-4F88-A72F-B406A828B978/data/Containers/Data/Application/44EBAF73-A23D-4DEF-B7CA-6C678C3AFC46/Documents". The return value for let name = URL(fileURLWithPath: yourPath).lastPathComponent turns out to be "Documents". It was able to grab the last component, but it wasn't able to get the name of the file.

Comment: @walt936 The name could be fetched by `fileURL.lastPathComponent` because this is where you assign the filename in the first place.

Comment: I was able to get the name of the file. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @walt936 Glad to have been able to help!

Comment: @walt936 If my answer was helpful, please consider accepting or upvoting it - this is usual practice on SO. If it wasn’t helpful, no worries :)